# Conjecture on $\pi(n)$ and other arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, conjectures

### $\text{Notations}$

Let $\pi(n)$ be the prime countiong function.

Let $\alpha(n)$ denote the number of prime factors of $n$ and $\beta(n)$ the sum of the prime factors of $n$. In other words, if $$n=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_m^{x_m}$$ then $\alpha(n)=m$ and $\beta(n)=p_1+p_2+...+p_m$

*(I changed the notations; It was pointed out in the comments that $\psi$ and $\omega$ are other functions and they were misleading)*

---

### $\text{Statement}$

> Let $\pi(n)$ be the prime counting function, $\psi(n)$ the number of
> prime factors and $\omega(n)$ the sum of the prime factors of $n$.
> Prove or disprove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that:
> $$\pi(n)=\alpha(n)\beta(n)$$

---

### $\text{Some other observations}$

Here are the first solutions:

```
4, 120, 437, 546, 620, 8144, 11509, 170049, 170907, 340655, 478476, 789575
```

Also, if we use the Prime Number Theorem ($\pi(n)$ is aproximatively $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$) we can derive solutions in an exhaustive manner. For example, find at what point $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}$ is aproximatively $\frac{47}{2}$ and then subtract $47$ from $n$ until you get the solution. Using this method we get $45764089927$ which in fact works.

---

### $\text{Why is it an interesting problem?}$

I find it rather interesting due to the unusual relationship between these $3$ functions. I played a while with several arithmetic functions and couldn't find strong conection between them, but the equation $\pi(n)=\alpha(n)\cdot\beta(n)$ seems promising.

Comment: Do not worry. This is more than enough context. The main problem to attack this nice problem is that it is difficult to find $\pi(n)$ for large $n$. Even with massive computational power and using all known formulas, apparently we only got upto about $10^{25}$. But there might be a non-constructive proof that infinite many solutions exist which I still would conjecture. On the other hand, such solutions are apparently very rare. Such questions anyway tend to be extremely difficult to decide, but they are nevertheless worth a deeper analysis.

Comment: I am glad you find it interesting, Peter.

Comment: I find the use of non-standard notation a bit confusing as $\omega(n)$ typically refers to the number of distinct primes dividing $n$. Also there are formulas that give the exact value of $\pi(x)$ for all $x\ge 0$ such as $\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\omega(n)\,M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ where $M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\mu(n)$ is Mertens function. The problem with these formulas is they're not very useful for computing $\pi(x)$ for large values of $x$ which is also the case for the more distant conjectured relationship which is the subject of this question.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Exact_form.

Comment: Also with respect to notation, in prime-number theory $\psi(x)$ typically refers to the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)$. Assuming $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\omega(n)$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing n, here's a few relationships perhaps relevant to this question: $f(x)=\sum\limits_{p\le x}\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\rfloor$ ($p\in\mathbb{P}$), $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\pi\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$, and $\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}\mu(n)\ f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ (see oeis.org/A013939).

Comment: Sorry for the notations...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive start I came up with (which is nothing but crude bounding) but it shows that if we divide such an $n$ by the largest prime divisor of itself, the remaining part should be small enough.

Suppose $p_m$ is the largest prime. Note that $\omega(n) \le m p_m$, so $\pi(n) \le m^2 p_m$, and $\omega(n) \ge p_m$, so $\pi(n) \ge m p_m \ge p_m$. Now note that $n \ge p_1 \cdots p_m \ge 2^m$, so $m \le \log_2 n$. Since for large enough $n$, $\pi(n)$ is bounded between $(1 \pm \varepsilon) \cdot \frac{n}{\ln n}$, we have the bounds $\frac{\ln n}{1 + \varepsilon} \le \frac{n}{p_m} \le \frac{(\ln n) \cdot (\log_2 n)^2}{1 - \varepsilon}$, and as a consequence of this, the fraction mentioned should be bounded above by the order of $(\ln n)^3$ and below by the order of $\ln n$.